# is there a fast way to aplly function to set of variables?

Tags: java, eclipse

Assume i have lots of variables

```
String not_id, not_section, not_steet, not_sqTotal, not_sqLiving, not_sqKitchen, not_flat, not_floor, not_floors, not_text, user_phone1, user_phone2, user_contact, not_region, not_district, not_settle, not_price, not_photo, not_date, not_date_till, not_up, not_premium, not_status;

not_id= not_section= not_steet= not_sqTotal= not_sqLiving=
                not_sqKitchen= not_flat= not_floor= not_floors= not_text=
                user_phone1= user_phone2= user_contact= not_region= not_district=
                not_settle= not_price= not_photo= not_date= not_date_till= not_up=
                not_premium= not_status=region_title=district_title=settle_title=section_title="";
```

i need to change their values using someFunction

```
not_id = someFunction(not_id);
```

How can i do such action for all variables?

Please, dont propose to use arrays, lists and other sort of collections if it assumes changing variable names to some uniform name.

I van to know if there is such possibility within java itself, eclipse ide or eclipse plugins.

Comment: The only way is to repeat the line... but why don't you just use an array (String[])?

Comment: You will end in a code duplication and maintenance hell with such variable declarations. Use a Map instead.

Comment: i need this  for gui, i dont know how i can work with gui using map

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is going to lead to somewhat unmaintainable code, but you could do it pretty easily with a regular expression search & replace on that second statement, replacing "var_name=" with "var_name = someFunction(var_name);".

Find:         ([^=])+=

Replace with: \1 = someFunction(\1);

Answer (score 1):

is `someFunction` a java method? or it is some simple transformer that is changing from `not_([a-z])(\w*)` to `not[A-Z]\2`? If you are only changing variable names use eclipse's excellent refactoring rename bound to `Ctrl+Shift+R` that can change all occurrences taking to account scope rules

Comment: it is a java method, but your tip is also helpfull